# D3 Slider stop event

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, d3.js

I have a D3 range slider in JS. I need to fire an event when sliders stops at a particular pair of points. I have coded like this:

```
d3.select('#slider4').call(d3.slider().axis(d3.svg.axis().ticks(6).tickFormat(function (d).value([0, 1]).on("slide", function (evt, value) { value1 = value[0], value2 = value[1]; loadChart(value1, value2); }));

function loadChart(value1, value2) {
    debugger;
    var data1 = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ChartData))');
    var low = Math.round(value1);
    var high = Math.round(value2);
    for (i = low + 1; i < high; i++) {
        debugger;
        if (i == 1) {
            freqData1 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "Jan";
            });
        }
        //freqData1.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        if (i == 2) {
            freqData2 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "Feb";
            });
            // freqData2.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.freq.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        }
        if (i == 3) {
            freqData3 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "Mar";
            });
            //freqData3.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.freq.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        }
        if (i == 4) {
            freqData4 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "Apr";
            });
            //freqData4.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.freq.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        }
        if (i == 5) {
            freqData5 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "May";
            });
            //freqData5.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.freq.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        }
        if (i == 6) {
            freqData6 = data1.filter(function(s) {
                return s.Month == "Jun";
            });
            //freqData6.forEach(function (d) { d.total = d.freq.Bonus + d.freq.Promotions + d.freq.Merchandise + d.freq.MobileCoupon; });
        }
    }

    var freqData = freqData1.map(function(obj, i) {
        debugger;
        var sum = {};
        for (var key in obj) {
            sum[key] = typeof obj[key] === 'number' ? obj[key] + freqData2[i][key] + freqData3[i][key] + freqData4[i][key] + freqData5[i][key] + freqData6[i][key] : obj[key];
        }
        return sum;
    });

    document.getElementById("dashboard").innerHTML = "";
    dashboard('#dashboard', freqData);
}
```

Here the overall code is to get the monthly and cumulative data for all the months between the sliders.

But this "slide" event fires every time I move the slider, But I actually needed to fire the event when slider stops. How can I achieve this?

Comment: It appears you've copy-pasted the first line incorrectly -- do you mind fixing that? Thanks.

Comment: can u please tell me the right syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/turban/d3.slider/blob/master/d3.slider.js#L43) for `d3.slider`, it has a `slideend` event.

Couple notes:

1. As @Qantas94Heavy mentions in his comment, your first line of code is busted.        `function (d).value` is incorrect syntax.
2. You future `d3` coding would be more maintainable/readable if you indented like:

   ```
   d3.select('#slider4')
     .call(
       d3.slider()
         .axis
     ) // more code here...
   ```